# I want to update my student record in the database, but its not working

Tags: python, django

The first problem is that when the update form is appeared date-of-birth field is not getting data from the database.
The Second thing is that whenever i click on the submit button it will not update my values in the databse.
The Third thing is after i click on the update or submit button it will automatically redirect to me in the insertion form which i don't want to be there (and i not even give the link or render to that page and i don't understand what is going on here beacause instead of it it will need to show my editstudent.html page not insertstudent.html page)
and YES!!! MY UPDATE IS ALSO NOT WORKING......
PLEASE HELP ME OUT AT THIS.......

editstudent.html PAGE:-

```
{% extends 'student/index.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-6">
    <!-- general form elements -->
    <div class="card card-primary">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Update Student Here</h3>
      </div>
      <!-- /.card-header -->
      <!-- form start -->
      <form action="{% url 'studentinsert' %}" role="form" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Student ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="id" placeholder="Enter Student ID" value="{{ student.sid }}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="firstname" placeholder="Enter First Name" value="{{ student.first_Name }}">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Last Name</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" value="{{ student.last_name }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Major</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="major" placeholder="Enter Major" value="{{ student.major }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Phone Number</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="phonenumber" placeholder="Enter the Phone Number" value="{{ student.phone }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">GPA</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="gpa" placeholder="Enter GPA" value="{{ student.gpa }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputFile">Date-of-Birth</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="custom-file">
                    <select name="DOBMonth" value="{{ student.date_of_birth }}">
                            <option>- Month -</option>
                            <option value="January">January</option>
                            <option value="Febuary">Febuary</option>
                            <option value="March">March</option>
                            <option value="April">April</option>
                            <option value="May">May</option>
                            <option value="June">June</option>
                            </select>                  
                    <select name="DOBDay" value="{{ student.date_of_birth }}>
                            <option>- Day -</option>
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            </select>
                            <select name="DOBYear" value="{{ student.date_of_birth }}>
                            <option>- Year -</option>
                            <option value="2020">2020</option>
                            <option value="2019">2019</option>
                            <option value="2018">2018</option>
                            <option value="2017">2017</option>
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                            <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.card-body -->

        <div class="card-footer">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.card -->
</div>
  {% endblock %}
```

My Views.py Page:-

```
def upstudent(request,pk):
    obj=Student.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method=="POST":
        iid=request.POST['id']
        firstname=request.POST['firstname']
        lastname=request.POST['lastname']
        major=request.POST['major']
        phonenumber=request.POST['phonenumber']
        gpa=request.POST['gpa']
        birth=request.POST['DOBDay']
        month=request.POST['DOBMonth']
        year=request.POST['DOBYear']
        d = Date()
        d.day = birth
        d.month = month
        d.year = year
        d.save()
        s=Student(Student.objects.get(id=obj))
        s.date_of_birth = d
        s.sid=iid
        s.first_Name=firstname
        s.last_name=lastname            
        s.major=major
        s.phone=phonenumber
        s.gpa=gpa
        s.save()
        return HttpResponse("Data is updated")
    else:
        student = Student.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request,"student/editstudent.html",{"student":student})
```

My Models.py Page:-

```
class Date(models.Model):
    month=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    day=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Student(models.Model):
    sid=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    first_Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    major=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gpa=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_of_birth = models.ForeignKey(Date,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

MY Urls.py Page:-

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("index",views.index,name="index"),
    path("studentinsert",views.studentinsert,name='studentinsert'),
    path("studentdata",views.studentdata,name="studentdata"),
    path("upstudent/<int:pk>",views.upstudent,name="upstudent")


]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of issues in your code:

1. Why is your `date_of_birth` linked via `ForeignKey` instead of `OneToOneField`? Can `Student` has more than 1 date of birth? Following changes will work if you swap it to one-to-one relation.
2. The first problem is that when the update form is appeared date-of-birth field is not getting data from the database.

Happens because there is no `value` attribute of `select` tag - you have to put `selected` attribute on `option` tag. Change your code to something like:

```
<select name="DOBMonth">
    <option>- Month -</option>
    <option value="January"{% if student.date_of_birth.month == 'January' %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>January</option>
    <option value="Febuary"{% if student.date_of_birth.month == 'Febuary' %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Febuary</option>
    <option value="March"{% if student.date_of_birth.month == 'March' %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>March</option>
    <option value="April"{% if student.date_of_birth.month == 'April' %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>April</option>
    <option value="May"{% if student.date_of_birth.month == 'May' %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>May</option>
    <option value="June"{% if student.date_of_birth.month == 'June' %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>June</option>
</select>
```

Same goes to day and year.

2. The Third thing is after i click on the update or submit button it will automatically redirect to me in the insertion form

It redirects you because `form` tag `action` attribute points to incorrect view. Currently it's `action="{% url 'studentinsert' %}"` and should be `action="{% url 'upstudent' pk=student.pk %}"`

3. The Second thing is that whenever i click on the submit button it will not update my values in the databse.

As @Mehran said, you should not refetch `Student`. Just do this:

```
obj.date_of_birth = d
obj.sid=iid
obj.first_Name=firstname
obj.last_name=lastname            
obj.major=major
obj.phone=phonenumber
obj.gpa=gpa
obj.save()
```

Learn [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/) - it will simplify your code greatly.

Comment: But the requirement is to create the different class of the  Date and that class has the fileds itself whish is DAY ,MONTH,YEAR

Comment: and where is d is coming from in my views file , which is i don't understand

Comment: Yeah, you can keep `Date` model. I just pointed the incorrect part of the code.

Comment: `d` is not in views at all. Corresponding `Date` is referred as `student.date_of_birth`.

Comment: but how do i update the day month and year becuase my all other data is working with updation but only day month year is not working

Comment: Did you change `Student` reference to `Date` to `OneToOneField` or it's still `ForeignKey` field?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, from the latest comment I think I understand what's going on. Here you are creating a NEW student or showing the already CREATED student data. I'll update the model and view.

**Models**

```
 class Student(models.Model):
     sid=models.CharField(max_length=200)
     first_Name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
     last_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
     major=models.CharField(max_length=200)
     phone=models.CharField(max_length=200)
     gpa=models.CharField(max_length=200)
     date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**Viiews**

```
 def upstudent(request,pk):
      student=Student.objects.filter(id=pk).first()

      if request.method=="POST":
           iid=request.POST['id']
           firstname=request.POST['firstname']
           lastname=request.POST['lastname']
           major=request.POST['major']
           phonenumber=request.POST['phonenumber']
           gpa=request.POST['gpa']
           datefield = request.post['datefield']  
           # depending on your datefield input, which will be a string 
           # this needs to be converted to a date object
           # use .strptime() function for this

           if not student:
                student = Student() # creating a new student object
           student.sid=iid
           student.first_Name=firstname
           student.last_name=lastname            
           student.major=major
           student.phone=phonenumber
           student.gpa=gpa
           student.date_of_birth = datefield
           student.save()
           return HttpResponse("Data is updated")
      else:
           return render(request,"student/editstudent.html",{"student":student})
```

**EDIT** Date type input in form: `​<input type="date" value="2010-12-16;">`

Comment: But what happen to the day , month , and the year fields in the views file they given me an error.What Should i do now.....and thanks for help

Comment: @GaganSharma I think the better approach for the date would be to use a DateField rather than a FK. If I'm not mistaken you used a FK to easily get how many students are there for one date/month/year later on, but that can be solved easily by using group by operations in Django ORM. This will allow you to select the specific date directly in the form template.

Comment: In views file they given me an error saying the d is undefined variable and in the updation form the data is not updating because as i said the insert is going on there instead of updation and it will create a new entry in the table instead of not update the exists field that i choose to update in the database

Comment: And as i said earlier in my editstudent.html form the field date is not picking the data from the database , so how i can  show the data here....please get back to me on this

Comment: @GaganSharma you should not have used the date in this way. I can't help you with the template but I'll update my answer with the django view and model that you should be using. The template needs changes on the date part. You don't need 3 fields just use a datefield in the form.

Comment: But Actually it is the requirement of the project that i have to create the Date class with the three different fields in it (Day,Month,Year) and that's why i'm using it otherwise i will definitely use the Datefield in it.

Comment: in that case you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/59005513/7183805 posted by @Gasanov

Answer (score 0):

You'r using wrong url name in form action

use `<form action="{% url 'upstudent' %}" role="form" method="POST">` instead of using `<form action="{% url 'studentinsert' %}" role="form" method="POST">`